# TypeScript auto capture array type variable in function

Tags: typescript, generics, type-inference

I tried code:

```js
nth(['a', 'b'], 1) // function nth<string[], 1>(o: string[], k: 1): string
nth<['a', 'b']>(['a', 'b'], 1) // function nth<["a", "b"], number | "0" | "1" | "length" | "toString" | "toLocaleString" | "pop" | "push" | "concat" | "join" | "reverse" | "shift" | "slice" | "sort" | "splice" | "unshift" | "indexOf" | ... 14 more ... | "values">(o: [...], k: number | ... 30 more ... | "values"): "a" | ... 29 more ... | (() => IterableIterator<...>)
nth<['a', 'b'], 1>(['a', 'b'], 1) // function nth<["a", "b"], 1>(o: ["a", "b"], k: 1): "b"

function nth<O, K extends keyof O>(o: O, k: K): O[K] {
  return o[k]
}
```

`nth<['a', 'b'], 1>(...)` works well, but is there any way to make `nth(...)` works as expected?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to create generic type for `nth` and apply it on function type definition. Example:

```js
type Nth<A extends any[], I extends number> = A[I];

type R = Nth<[1, 2, 3], 1>

function nth<A extends any[], I extends number>(o: A, k: I): Nth<A, I> {
  return o[k]
}

let result = nth(['a', 'b'], 1)
let result1 = nth<['a', 'b'], 1>(['a', 'b'], 1)
let result2 = nth<['a', 'b'], 1>(['a', 'b'], 1);
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=type%20Nth%3CA%20extends%20any%5B%5D%2C%20I%20extends%20number%3E%20%3D%20A%5BI%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20R%20%3D%20Nth%3C%5B1%2C%202%2C%203%5D%2C%201%3E%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20nth%3CA%20extends%20any%5B%5D%2C%20I%20extends%20number%3E(o%3A%20A%2C%20k%3A%20I)%3A%20Nth%3CA%2C%20I%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20return%20o%5Bk%5D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20result%20%3D%20nth(%5B'a'%2C%20'b'%5D%2C%201)%0D%0Alet%20result1%20%3D%20nth%3C%5B'a'%2C%20'b'%5D%2C%201%3E(%5B'a'%2C%20'b'%5D%2C%201)%0D%0Alet%20result2%20%3D%20nth%3C%5B'a'%2C%20'b'%5D%2C%201%3E(%5B'a'%2C%20'b'%5D%2C%201)%3B)

It's behavior that you expect?

---Edited---

If you want to received "b" instead of string you can do something like this:

```js
type Nth<A extends string[], I extends number> = A[I];
let result = nth(['a', 'b'], 1) // string 
let result = nth(['a', 'b'] as ['a', 'b'], 1) // string 
let result1 = nth<['a', 'b'], 1>(['a', 'b'], 1) // 'b'
let result2 = nth<['a', 'b'], 1>(['a', 'b'], 1); // 'b'
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but the result still not what I expected, with your suggestion: 

`let result = nth(['a', 'b'], 1) // => result is string (I hope result is "b" in this writing)`

Comment: @c4605 try `function nth<A extends [V]| V[], I extends number, V extends string | number | boolean | undefined | null | object>(o: A, k: I): Nth<A, I> {
  return o[k]
}

const result = nth(['a', 'b'], 1) // we need a const othweise the type will be widened`

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue here is that `['a', 'b']` is actually typed by TypeScript as `string[]`, so accessing an element in that array will give you `string`.  Conceptually you are wanting `['a', 'b']` to be typed as a tuple.  For example:

```
const array = ['a', 'b']
const str = array[1] // this is typed as string

const tuple: ['a', 'b'] = ['a', 'b']
const b = tuple[1]   // this is typed as 'b'
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=const%20array%20%3D%20%5B'a'%2C%20'b'%5D%0D%0Aconst%20str%20%3D%20array%5B1%5D%20%2F%2F%20this%20is%20typed%20as%20string%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20tuple%3A%20%5B'a'%2C%20'b'%5D%20%3D%20%5B'a'%2C%20'b'%5D%0D%0Aconst%20b%20%3D%20tuple%5B1%5D%20%20%20%2F%2F%20this%20is%20typed%20as%20'b')

TypeScript does not automatically infer array literals as tuples as that can cause some problems - see [this issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/22679) for a bit more context.

In your case, it should work as you expect via:

```
nth(['a', 'b'] as ['a', 'b'], 1)

// or
const value: ['a', 'b'] = ['a', 'b']
nth(value, 1)
```